# jQuery - Add CSS to Child Element based on parent elements class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add a CSS style (to set the height of the child element) to a child element which has no class name. The parent element, however, does have a unique class name.

This is what I've got:-

```
function createStickyMenu() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var menucontainer = $('<div id="main_menu"></div>');

    maincontainer.find('.logo').css({
        'float': 'left',
    });

    maincontainer.find('.logo').children.css({
        'height': '57px',
    });
});
```

The simplified HTML is like so:-

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
       <img src="#">
    </a>
</div>
```

I therefore need to add a height to the img tag. How can I target this element specifically without adding a class name to the img tag? My attempt as above does add the CSS float: left to the 'logo' class element, but not to its child (which I think should be the img tag).

Comment: Try `.children()`, not `.children`

Comment: `var $ = jQuery` is useless. `$` is already an alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: if the values for the properties are not computed via js my advice is to keep off css from js

Comment: Works perfectly - cannot believe it was as simple as that, been trying to figure it out for hours. Will hopefully refactor later and remove useless code, so will take on your comments about $ onboard. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I initially hoped to keep it all CSS, but with having a sticky on desktop view and not mobile and a few other changes, I decided to use some variables instead to keep things a little bit simpler. It works, may not be the perfect solution, but it works!

Comment: ok, anyway you may still use css mediaqueries to detect a mobile device

Comment: You're welcome. During your refactoring, also note that you're doing twice `maincontainer.find('.logo')`. You could chain everything : `maincontainer.find('.logo').css({'float': 'left'}).children().css({'height': '57px'})`. Also, remove extra commas after 'left' and '57px'.

Answer (score 0):

`$( "a.logo" ).children().css( "width", "200px" );`
`$( "a.logo" ).children().css( "height", "200px" );`

Note: There "a.logo" have no space